# Is there a Concept (collection) which has no definition in English (natural language)

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, philosophy

This is a kind of soft question but I prefer to ask it here where people understand more mathematics rather than on some philosophy or language forum.

An instance of Cantor's theorem, the [Grelling paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grelling%E2%80%93Nelson_paradox) gives rise to the following.

Consider the set $Adj$ of all (English) adjectives. We have the following function $f : Adj × Adj \to \{0,1\}$ defined for all adjectives $a_1$ and $a_2$,

$$f(a_1,a_2)=\cases{1 ~~\text{ if } a_2 ~\text{ describes } ~a_1; \\0 ~~\text{ if } a_2 ~\text{ does not describe } ~a_1.}$$
so with $\neg:\{0,1\}\to \{0,1\}$ which sends $0$ to $1$, and $1$ to $0$ we arrive at the following diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Adj\times Adj @>f>> \{0,1\}\\
@A \Delta A A= @VV \neg V\\
Adj @>>\chi> \{0,1\}
\end{CD}
where $\chi$ characterize some subset of adjectives that can not be described by any adjectives (by Cantor's theorem).

I wonder, if this (or some similar) construction tells us that there is a concept which has no definition in English (a natural language)?

**EDIT**: At first sight the term "concept" in the initial variant of question is rather ambiguous;  in a vide sense a concept for me means everything we percept by consciousness.

On the other hand I feel comfortable to think that all naive-set theoretic collections are kinds of concepts. But inverse is not clear for me, I like to think that there may be concept which does not form a collection.  In order to eliminate ambiguity of the term "concept" readuce a search area and  let us consider only members of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ which is uncountable.

Then as lulu suggest there are uncountably many concepts and by Cantor's theorem, counting argument shows that some subsets of $\mathbb N$ lack of definition in English.

And as I see a situation doesn't change if instead of English I consider some countably infinite language. And definition is defined as finite collection of words in the language.

Sorry if set-theory tag is not relevant at least it may attract attention of the people who have thought about something similar.

Comment: I thibnk simple counting arguments should do it.  There are only finitely many concepts that can be expressed using  English sentences of bounded length, and only countably many that can be expressed with finite English sentences of arbitrary length.  And, whatever one means by "concept" I have to imagine that there are uncountably many of them.

Comment: to get an actual answer you need to give us a precise definition of "concept".

Comment: @lulu The downward Lowenheim Skolem theorem guarantees that any theory satisfied by an uncountable model will also be satisfied by a countable one. So even if there are uncountably many "concepts" then we can satisfy a theory of them with a countable model. In addition, the theory we use will necessarily have finitely many characters.

Comment: @user400188 The Lowenheim-Skolem theorem always fascinated me. What is it we lernt actually from that you have written. I do not see clearly a conclusion I should do from this staff.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov I was trying to point out that it isn't necessarily relevant whether there are uncountably many "concepts" or not, however they are defined. This is because we can satisfy any theory of them with a countable model.

Comment: The issue is: what is "a concept which has no definition in natural language" ? How can we "speak of it" outside natural language ? IMO it is not easy to transfer to natural language the mathematical "construction" that compares the uncountability of power-set (of an infinite set) with the countability of the expression of the formal language.

Comment: Assuming, as lulu correctly does, that there are "only countably many expressions with of arbitrary length", where are their "meanings" ?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Way better if there are no meanings of some of them. I do not see what do you suggest?

Comment: The issue is "How to define a concept that is not definable with language?"

Comment: We can not define a concept inside a language which is not definable in the language but why it is an issue. For me a concept arrives in perception not inside of a language. And I ask If we can proof that there is a concept (definitely not by constructing it precisely) which has no definition inside e.g. a natural language.

In diagram above $\chi$ characterize a subset (and hence a concept) which is impredicable,  (is not representable by $f$) there is no predicate which is true about the subset, but I can not see why is it issue? 
Am I missing something you see and I do not understand?